# How to get salary on hours worked?

Tags: mysql

i'm trying to get the employee's salary depending on the hours worked.

I made this query but the operation to get the salary isn't working well

```
SELECT t.id_usuario as jobber_id,
   COUNT(DISTINCT t.nombre_orden_trabajo) as total_tareas,
   sum(t.HORA_TERMINO - t.HORA_INICIO) * t.pago_jobber as pago_jober
   FROM tareas t join usuarios u
   on(t.id_usuario = u.id_usuario)
   WHERE u.PAIS = "CL"
   GROUP BY t.ID_USUARIO;
```

I get this

[image]

pago_jober ( user id salary ) is wrong, i even get negative salaries.

these are my columns:

[image]

pago_jobber means salary per hour

hora_inicio means starting hour to work

hora_termino means final hour to work

I subtracted these two columns then multiplied them with pago_jober (salary per hour) but the result is wrong

Comment: try to remove `sum` function and leave `( )` as it

Comment: It isn't working bro... i get wrong result.

Comment: Can you post your table's DDL, be sure that you have correct column types especially for the hora_* field, or you may have incorrect results. For example: `'15:30:00' - '15:00:00'` will result zero.

Comment: I think the column data types are correct bro, look at them https://i.ibb.co/4Pqzr4G/datatype.png
They are like text (varchar i guess)